# How to export a project from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi my main question while using visual studio code is how can i export the program of a website from VS. I want it like we can do in html notepad. after saving html we get a shortcut but how can i get the same with VS ?

Comment: VS or VSC, both have their files on your local disk

Comment: what and how do you get shortcut with Notepad,